# Outlook (2019): How to automatically CC the sender on outgoing email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

I'm aware I can setup a rule to automatically cc outgoing mail to a specific email address in outgoing email. However, I dont want to set a specific email address - but have it cc whoever the mail is being sent from - is this possible?

For example, I have 3 email addresses:
john@site1.com / john@site2.org / john@site3.me

- When I send email from john@site1.com - Outlook automatically BCC's john@site1.com.
- When I send email from john@site2.org - Outlook automatically BCC's john@site2.org.
- When I send email from john@site3.me - Outlook automatically BCC's john@site3.me.

Comment: Outlook doesn't have an option to realize this. I found on post in Outlook uservoice: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/13834191-bcc-to-be-part-of-email-chain-via-auto-reply-to-bc   maybe we can vote

Answer (score 0):

No way with rules only. You'll need to write a VBA macro or use a third-party add-in.